# Flutter macOS plugin

Tags: macos, flutter, plugins

I'm making a Flutter plugin which must support macOS. However, when I want to create a plugin and run the plugin in the example app (even when I haven't edited the by Flutter generated code), Xcode throws the following error.

Unable to load contents of the file list: '/Users/admin/../example/macos/ephemeral/FlutterInputs.xcfilelist'

Unable to load contents of the file list: '/Users/admin/../example/macos/ephemeral/FlutterOutputs.xcfilelist'

[image: Xcode error screenshot]

This is my Flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel dev, 1.21.0-9.0.pre, on Mac OS X 10.15.3 19D76, locale
    nl-NL)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.5)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.48.0)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Images of error message may convey information beyond the text, but the text within them is not searchable or accessible. Please [edit] the question to include the text of the error message.

Answer (score 16):

I found another solution:
Run the flutter build command `flutter build macos` before build in Xcode, then these input/out files appears.

- FlutterInputs.xcfilelist
- FlutterOutputs.xcfilelist

Answer (score 2):

```
1. flutter clean
2. delete 'Pods/', 'Podfile.lock', 'runner.xcworkspace'
3. pod deintegrate
4. flutter pub get
5. pod install
```

These commands in sequence did the job for me

Comment: This worked for me. Make sure to `cd` to `macos` folder before running `pod deintegrate`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. When I created a Flutter Plugin these files weren't created. But when I created a Flutter Project these files where. When I copy/pasted those files to my plugin, the project build successfully!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using the correct version of flutter which matching with my project dependency. I used the latest version of a flutter but my project is not supporting that version so downgrade the version and the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to make sure `arm64` is set as *Excluded Architectures* field in Xcode Build Settings:

1. Open `Runner.xcworkspace` in Xcode
2. Select Runner project from *Project navigator*
3. Select Runner under **PROJECT** section
4. Click on *Build Settings*
5. Set `arm64` for *Excluded Architectures* field
6. Repeat for Pods

Note: this only applies for Apple Silicon Macs.

Comment: I tried this and the build failed with the message: "A build only device cannot be used to run this target."